# How to put Table Headers in <thead> in tiptap

Tags: weasyprint, tiptap

I have been using weasyprint to convert HTML to pdf and I wanted to repeat the headers of the table when they get split onto new page in the pdf. Weasyprint respects the 'thead' tag headers and repeat them on the new page when the table get split.
But by default tiptap renders the table rows in 'tbody' tag and even in toggleHeaderRow() it doesn't make a new  tag rather it uses 'th' to make table headers.

Is there any way to achieve what i want. any guidance would help. thanks :)